# Is there any way to make generic action method in Controller(ODataController)?

Tags: c#, .net-core, odata

Is there any way to make action method generic in controllers? I have made an Odata Controller and set custom routes in such a way that every odata request go to same controller.

Current Scenario:

```
public IEnumerable<Book> Get()
{
  return (IEnumerable<Book>)data;
}

public IEnumerable<Customer> Get()
{
  return (IEnumerable<Customer>)data;
}
```

Custom Odata Routing:

```
public class CustomRouting: IODataRoutingConvention
    {
        private readonly string ControllerName = "Handel";

        public IEnumerable<ControllerActionDescriptor> SelectAction(RouteContext routeContext)
        {
            var odataPath = routeContext.HttpContext.ODataFeature().Path;


            if (!(odataPath.Segments.FirstOrDefault() is EntitySetSegment))
            {
                return Enumerable.Empty<ControllerActionDescriptor>();
            }

            // Get a IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider from the global service provider.
            IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actionCollectionProvider =
                routeContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider>();

            IEnumerable<ControllerActionDescriptor> actionDescriptors = actionCollectionProvider
                    .ActionDescriptors.Items.OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>()
                    .Where(c => c.ControllerName == ControllerName);
            SelectControllerResult controllerResult = new SelectControllerResult(ControllerName, null);
            IList<IODataRoutingConvention> routingConventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();
            foreach (NavigationSourceRoutingConvention nsRouting in routingConventions.OfType<NavigationSourceRoutingConvention>())
            {

                string actionName = nsRouting.SelectAction(routeContext, controllerResult, actionDescriptors);

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(actionName))
                {
                    var actionDesc = actionDescriptors.Where(
                        c => String.Equals(c.ActionName, actionName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                    return actionDesc;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Expected Action Method:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Get()
{
  return (IEnumerable<T>)data;
}
```

Where T can be of any type: Book, Customer

OData URL:

```
~/odata/Book?$filter=Name eq 'Book1'

~/odata/Customer?$select=Name,Publisher
```

The generic action method is not getting listed in action descriptor (actionDesc) which i made in CustomRouting class.Am i writing the correct generic action method?
Please suggest me with concrete solution.

Comment: You can create a generic controller and then pass T to the action methods (see [here](https://www.ben-morris.com/generic-controllers-in-asp-net-core/)). I don't think you can create a generic action methods. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thank you @IvanB your suggestion was helpful